# Transforming a normal distribution to a uniform one

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm searching for a method that transforms a normal distribution into a normal distribution. I've looked everywhere, but I'm not sure if I just missed something completely obvious, if this actually is a really hard question or if I searched in the wrong places.

Say, I have some data which is normally distributed (by reading from a device which creates such data from sensor inputs for example, which are distributed this way). How can I then get a uniform distribution of the data? I have seen plenty of algorithms for the other way around.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "uniform distribution *of the data*" (emphasis mine)? If your goal is to produce uniformly distributed samples given normally distributed samples, and the normally distributed samples happen to be i.i.d (independent and identically distributed), with zero mean, then you can take a pair of them, say X and Y, and treat them as the coordinates of a 2-dimensional real vector. The angle of this vector will be uniformly distributed on an interval of length $2\pi$.

Comment: This is pretty much what I meant. So, actually, that would really be a very simple solution to my problem. May I ask why that is the case? I'm really curious on how that can be shown. Thank you!

Comment: It's because the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is circularly symmetric. You can show it rigorously but that's the fundamental reason.

Comment: This is something I would not have guessed, works too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $N$ be a normally distributed variable, 
with mean 0 and variance 1 (substract the mean and divide by the standard deviation in order be in this case).

You look for a certain (smooth, increasing) $f:\Bbb R\to[0,1]$ such as
$
f(N)
$ is uniform, that is:
$$
P(f(N) \le q) = q
$$for every $q\in(0,1)$.

Under regularity assumptions, this is
$$
q = P(N \le f^{-1}(q)) = \mathcal N(f^{-1}(q))
\\
\iff f^{-1}(q) = \mathcal N^{-1}(q)
\iff f(q) = \mathcal N(q)
$$
with $\mathcal N(x) = P(N \le x)$.

Now check the smoothness assumptions (in particular, $\mathcal N$ is increasing).

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried it and it worked like a charm. So it really was something rather easy. I did not see this connection!

Comment: We call $P(N \le x)$ the *cumulative distribution function* for random variable $N$.  In this case the normal distribution was "normalized" to have mean $0$ and variance $1$, but the same trick works with any continuous probability distribution.